# Reverse legend order pandas plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have following code to show stacked bar

```
handles = df.toPandas().set_index('x').T.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, figsize=(11,11))
    plt.legend(loc='best', title="Line", fontsize = 'small', framealpha=0)
    plt.ylabel("'" + lineName + "'")
    plt.show()
```

I want to reverse the order of legend I used `handles=handles[::-1]`but I got an error.

Comment: Please include the error that occured, and some details about what this data frame is.

Comment: For how to reverse the data frame, have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20444087/right-way-to-reverse-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's a minimal example using matplotlib directly for the legend.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.random.randn(10) + 1, 'b': np.random.randn(10),
                   'c': np.random.randn(10) - 1}, columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
ax = df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(reversed(handles), reversed(labels), loc='upper left')  # reverse both handles and labels
```

[image: bar chart]

(I've used plt.style.use('ggplot') in the plot above.)

See also the [matplotlib legend guide](http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html?highlight=legend).

Answer (score 19):

[`DataFrame.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) takes a `legend` argument, which can be True/False/'reverse'. You want `legend='reverse'`

Comment: It didn`t work :df.toPandas().set_index('Product_Line_Name').T.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, figsize=(11,11), legend='reverse')
    plt.legend(loc='best', title="Line", fontsize = 'small', framealpha=0)
    plt.ylabel("'" + lineName + "'")
    plt.show()

Comment: Your second legend overwrites the first one.

Comment: @Goyo can I add second legend parameters to plot? or in legend say reverse it?