# How to reverse the legends of stacked barplot in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, data-visualization

I have a dataset with a few records about some crop production by year. So I am visualizing the top produced crop by each year in a stacked bar chart. Dataset  I have used can be found in [kaggle PMFBY Coverage.csv](https://www.kaggle.com/pyatakov/india-pmfby-statistics).

Here is my code.

```py
# Top Crop by year
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))

df_crg_[df_crg_.year==2018].groupby('cropName').size().nlargest(5).plot(kind='barh', color='red', label='2018')
df_crg_[df_crg_.year==2019].groupby('cropName').size().nlargest(5).plot(kind='barh', color='green', label='2019')
df_crg_[df_crg_.year==2020].groupby('cropName').size().nlargest(5).plot(kind='barh', color='blue', label='2020')
df_crg_[df_crg_.year==2021].groupby('cropName').size().nlargest(5).plot(kind='barh', color='maroon', label='2021')

plt.legend(loc="upper right")
plt.xlabel('Total Production Time')
plt.title('Top Crop by year')
plt.show()
```

And this was the output
[image]

Now if you look at the graph you would notice the stacked bar chart legends are revered, it is showing 2021 status first instead of 2018. So I want to reverse this order of representation.

I found one [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54874269/ordering-of-elements-in-pandas-stacked-bar-chart/54875576) for this question but I don't know how to apply it, as it is assigning plotting commands to one variable but in my case, there are four plotting commands.

---

Only this answer would do, but if know and can answer any other method of extracting top produced crop by year then that would be great. If you notice here I am manually going through each year then extracting that year's top crop. I tried doing it with groupby but I wasn't able to get the answer.

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you're plotting several bar plots on top of each other, not stacking them. Also, the 4 plots probably use different orderings of the crops, generating a weird mix. This means that stacking these bars isn't feasible. You should first try to plot the bars on 4 different subplots to serve as a reference.

Comment: `pd.crosstab(df['sssyName.year'], df['cropName']).T.sort_values(2018, ascending=False)` Your plot seems to assume the nlargest is the same for each year.

Comment: Something more like `pd.crosstab(df['sssyName.year'], df['cropName']).T.sort_values(2018, ascending=False).head().plot(kind='barh', stacked=True)`, but this sorts by 2018

Comment: Thanks, @TrentonMcKinney, but actually I want n top-produced crop each year. Do you have any idea for that?

Comment: That's why I said "Something more like" and "but this sorts by 2018"

Comment: yeah, but this won't work, thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, the same 5 crops need to be selected each year. Otherwise, you can't have a fixed ordering on the y-axis.

The easiest way to get a plot with the *overall* 5 most-frequent crops, is seaborn's `sns.countplot` and limiting to the 5 largest. Note that seaborn is strongly objected to stacked bar plots, so you'll get "dodged" bars (which are easier to compare, year by year, and crop by crop):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('PMFBY coverage.csv')

sns.set_style('white')
order = df.groupby('cropName').size().sort_values(ascending=False)[:5].index
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 5))
ax = sns.countplot(data=df, y='cropName', order=order, hue='year')
for bars in ax.containers:
    ax.bar_label(bars, fmt='%.0f', label_type='edge', padding=2)
sns.despine()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.countplot example]

With pandas, you can get stacked bars, but you need a bit more manipulation:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('PMFBY coverage.csv')
sns.set_style('white')
order = df.groupby('cropName').size().sort_values(ascending=False)[:5].index
df_5_largest = df[df['cropName'].isin(order)]
df_5_largest_year_count = df_5_largest.groupby(['cropName', 'year']).size().unstack('year').reindex(order)
ax = df_5_largest_year_count.plot.barh(stacked=True, figsize=(12, 5))
ax.invert_yaxis()
for bars in ax.containers:
    ax.bar_label(bars, fmt='%.0f', label_type='center', color='white', fontsize=16)
sns.despine()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: pandas stacked bars]

Now, compare this with how the bars would look like if you'd consider the 5 largest crops of each individual year. Notice how the crops and their order is different each year. How would you combine such information to a single plot?

```py
sns.set_style('white')
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(14, 8))

df[df.year == 2018].groupby('cropName').size().nlargest(5).plot(kind='barh', color='C0', title='2018', ax=axs[0, 0])
df[df.year == 2019].groupby('cropName').size().nlargest(5).plot(kind='barh', color='C1', title='2019', ax=axs[0, 1])
df[df.year == 2020].groupby('cropName').size().nlargest(5).plot(kind='barh', color='C2', title='2020', ax=axs[1, 0])
df[df.year == 2021].groupby('cropName').size().nlargest(5).plot(kind='barh', color='C3', title='2021', ax=axs[1, 1])
for ax in axs.flat:
    ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0], fmt='%.0f', label_type='edge', padding=2)
    ax.margins(x=0.1)
sns.despine()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: bars for 5 largest crops for each year]

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I corrected my single graph to subplots, thanks to your earlier comment above. Thanks for this awesome answer btw can you tell what the `order` command is doing? Is it also selecting top 5 with the same order as of grouped and sliced data above.

Comment: I am getting an error `AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'bar_label'` with your code.

Comment: You seem to be running an old matplotlib version.  `bar_label` is new since `matplotlib 3.4`. The code will still work if you remove those calls.

Comment: `order=` in `sns.countplot`  (and similar functions) here sets a list of y-values. That list defines both the order and the subset of all possible y-values.   In this case, the list is created from the index of the sorted groupby-by dataframe.

Comment: A bit of an off-topic here: If you were interested in the order of legend entries in a _vertical_ barchart, use `handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels();
ax.legend(reversed(handles), reversed(labels))`