# Pandas Split Function in Reverse

Tags: python, pandas, split

I have a Pandas Dataframe with a column that looks like this:

```
    Car_Make
0   2017 Abarth 124 Spider ManualConvertible
1   2017 Abarth 124 Spider AutoConvertible
2   2017 Abarth 124 Spider ManualConvertible
3   2017 Abarth 124 Spider AutoConvertible
4   2017 Abarth 595 ManualHatch
5   2017 Abarth 595 AutoHatch
```

Three Questions:

1 [How to save split data in panda in reverse order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40069551/how-to-save-split-data-in-panda-in-reverse-order/40069615#40069615) - This solves my problem but I don't know how or why it works - can someone please explain this to me? I hate copy pasting without understanding why it works

```
df['Car_Make'].apply(lambda x:pd.Series(x.split()[::-1]))
```

2 I have tried to replicate it using a user-defined function (that I can use again) with the following, but it doesn't appear to work (any help understanding why and the correct way to turn the Lambda function into a user-defined function

```
def f(x):
    df[x] = pd.Series(x.split()[::-1])
    return df
```

3 Is there a better way to split this column by space in reverse?

I have tried using Regex which works, but not on all rows as you can see row 4 and 5 a slightly different to the above.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Adrian

Comment: What do you want the resulting data frame to look like?  Split on each space, or something else?

Comment: Split on each space is fine (just in reverse). I'm interested in 'ManualConvertible' (or the last part of the entry). I'm sure an advanced regex expression could solve this, but I only know basic expressions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a shot at your three questions:

1) Why does `df['Car_Make'].apply(lambda x:pd.Series(x.split()[::-1]))` work?

Break it down:

1. `df['Car_Make']` - the column with the data you want to operate on
2. `.apply()` - a `pandas` DataFrame and Series method that will apply a function to either every column, or every row, in a DataFrame, or to every row in a Series.
3. `lambda x:` - the function that will be applied by the `.apply()` method to every row of the Series. `x` represents the record object, which in your case is the string containing the `Car_Make` entries.
4. `pd.Series()` - this will convert the value inside it into a `pandas` Series.
5. `x.split()` - As mentioned in point 3, `x` is your string object, and `split()` is a string method that, when passed with no parameters, defaults to splitting a string by its spaces and returning each split object into a list.
6. `[::-1]` - A handy list iterator that reverses a list, such as that returned by `x.split()`. The syntax for list iteration is `[start_index:end_index:step]`. Using a -1 step iterates through the list backwards.

Put that all together, and that code is iterating through every record in `df['Car_Make']`, splitting them, reversing the order of the split items, and returning the reversed list as a pandas Series object.

2) Replicating that with a defined function.

You are really close, only that the function needs to take a row/record as its argument, and needs to be called in the `.apply()` method. What you want to do is replace the `lambda x`, not the way it is applied.

Using what you have so far:

```
def f(x):
    return pd.Series(x.split()[::-1])

df['Car_Make'].apply(f)
```

3) Is there a better way?

If you want to split a string and then reverse the order of the items, no, this is a great way. If you only want to split a certain part of a string starting from the right, then `rsplit()` is a good method.

Comment: This is very helpful and exactly what I wanted. Thanks for taking the time to explain that to me. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
df.car_make.str.rsplit(' ', 1, expand=True)
# returns:
                        0                  1
0  2017 Abarth 124 Spider  ManualConvertible
1  2017 Abarth 124 Spider    AutoConvertible
2  2017 Abarth 124 Spider  ManualConvertible
3  2017 Abarth 124 Spider    AutoConvertible
4         2017 Abarth 595        ManualHatch
5         2017 Abarth 595          AutoHatch
```

Comment: That works. Didn't know there was an rsplit function - does what I need it to do. If you can explain (for my own knowledge how that Lambda function works), that would be awesome!

Answer (score 1):

The code you're asking here:

```
df['Car_Make'].apply(lambda x:pd.Series(x.split()[::-1]))
```

There are several things going on here:

1.) First, lambda are basically impromptu functions.  In this case, it's an unnamed function taking the argument `x`, and returns `pd.Series(x.split()[::-1]`.  More on `x` later.

2.) `pd.Series(...)` as you know creates a pandas Series object much like your original data.

3.) `x.split()` is splitting the string `x` with space as a separator by default.

4.) The `[::-1]` bit is a [`slice`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation).  Much like `range()`, it takes 3 params, `[start: end: steps]`.  In this case, it's saying to get the string from start to end, but use `-1` as steps, i.e. in reverse.  Note that only the `end` param is mandatory.

5.) The main function here is `apply()` on your `df['Car_Make']` series, which is essentially a list of strings.  `apply()` takes a function (much like `map()`) and apply it to the `df['Car_Make']` series.  In this case, it's applying the lambda, which takes the data of your series and use it as argument `x` for the function.

6.) Putting everything back together.  The statement is:

- passing the `df['Car_Make']` string data as `x` to the `lambda`
- `lambda` then process the `x.split()` to split the string data into list.
- The list is then sorted in reverse order by the slice `[::-1]`.
- `pd.Series()` now convert the list into a `Series` object.
- The `Series` object is then returned by lambda to your `apply()` function.
- The `apply()` function then return the resulting `Series` object, which conveniently, is the reverse sorted string you wanted in a Series.

If all you care about is the very last split though, you really don't need to do the reverse split and all that.  You could easily have done the following and it would have returned the very last item in the split right away:

`data['Car Make'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series({'Car_Make':x.split()[-1]}))`

```
            Car_Make
0  ManualConvertible
1    AutoConvertible
2  ManualConvertible
3    AutoConvertible
4        ManualHatch
5          AutoHatch
```

Thank you for asking this question, I learned a few stuff about `pandas` during this answer as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me. Very useful. Already thinking of things I can apply this too! Appreciate your time