# How to solve this data set

Tags: python-3.x

I am importing a Data set from quandl using API. Everything is perfect, however the time series I am importing is reversed. By this I mean if I used the `.head` method to print the first elements in the data set, I will get the latest Data set figures and printing the tail will get oldest figures

df = pd.read_csv("https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/CHRIS/CME_CD4.csv?api_key=H32H8imfVNVm9fcEX6kB",parse_dates=['Date'],index_col='Date')

df.head()

Answer (score 0):

This should be a pretty easy fix if I understand. Credit to behzad.nouri on this answer [Right way to reverse pandas.DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20444087/right-way-to-reverse-pandas-dataframe).

You just need to reverse the order of your dataframe using the line below.
`df = df.reindex(index=df.index[::-1])`