# Reversing the order of only the rows in Pandas Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, database, dataframe

hello is there a way I could reverse the order of the rows. I have used the function  `data1 = data.iloc[::-1]` which reverses all the values within the data table including the row numbers, however  I only want it to reverse the values and leave the rows as is. So I would like `row 0 : Open:242.5`  , `row 1 : Open:243.95`  and so on. At the image below you can also see how the rows start at `row#; 1862` and should be `row#; 1862`

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Right way to reverse pandas.DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20444087/right-way-to-reverse-pandas-dataframe) One of the answers there mentions resetting the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a reset_index to reset your index after you've reversed it.

```
data=data.iloc[::-1].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just [`reset_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html#pandas.DataFrame.reset_index) after.

```
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just reset the index in case of ordered indexes:

```
data1 = data.iloc[::-1].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Or else save the previous index and apply it again, this will work even if the index os not ordered:

```
indexes = data.index
data1 = data.iloc[::-1]
data1.index = indexes
```