# When i used bar type barh in pandas , values in y axis displays in descending order instead of ascending order from top

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

[image]

```
plt.figure(figsize=(50, 30)) 
Comparison.plot(x='Country', kind='bar', stacked=True,title='Stacked Bar Graph by dataframe')
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the original dataset, I suggest manually ordering the `Comparison` dataframe, e.g.:

```py
Comparison.sort_index(ascending=True, ignore_index=True, inplace=True)
Comparison.plot(x='Country', kind='bar', stacked=True, title='Stacked Bar Graph by dataframe')
```

For other approaches see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20444087/right-way-to-reverse-a-pandas-dataframe).

Comment: Thanks for replying but it didnt work . Its still showing in Descending order .

Comment: What is the original dataset? It can be halepful I we know what is exactly the dataframe index,  the type of it.