# Get moving average of list of panda dataframes starting from first row, not last

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of panda dataframe;

[image]

I would like to convert it into a panda dataframe that looks like this;

[image]

I tried something like `panda_series.rolling(window=3).mean()`. However, the problem is that the moving average is calculated starting from the last row. What I want is to have the moving average to be calculated starting from the first row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compute the [`rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rolling.html?highlight=rolling#pandas.Series.rolling) on the reversed Series, and set the `min_periods` to 1:

```
df['MA3'] = df['value'][::-1].rolling(window=3, min_periods=1).mean()
```

Output:

```
   value   MA3
0     12  13.0
1     13  14.0
2     14  14.5
3     15  15.0
```

Note that it is not necessary to reverse the output if you assign it back as a column due to the fact that pandas performs index alignement before inserting the data.

If you're working with an isolated Series, however, you will need to use:

```
s = df['value'][::-1].rolling(window=3, min_periods=1).mean()[::-1]

# or
# s2 = s1[::-1].rolling(window=3, min_periods=1).mean()[::-1]
```

Comment: your answer is almost perfect. To get the right order in the panda series as required in the question, the panda series in your answer needs to be reversed again. I wrote an answer to build on your answer. Do you mind editing your answer to make it perfect?

Comment: @FDL you only need to reverse it again if you work with the Series alone, if you assign it to a column, index alignement will do the job ;) I added this to the answer

Comment: As far as performance goes, there's an interesting answer about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65391420/11865956)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to build on the answer by @mozway. Credit goes to him.

To get the right order in the panda series as required in the question, here's the code.

```
df['MA3'] = df['value'][::-1].rolling(window=3, min_periods=1).mean()
df['MA3'] = df['MA3'][::-1]
```